# multiple lines plot using multiple groups in data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Based on the certain conditions, I want to plot the data as given below:

```
WC     ASL  TS  LPD
7101    3   L   573.57
7101    3   L   323.33
7102    4   R   113.36
7102    4   R   3.05
7103    7   L   204.72
7103    7   L   123.65
7104    21  R   252.36
7104    21  R   225.74
7104    21  R   147.79
7104    21  R   151.47
7105    27  L   350.51
7105    27  L   41.61
7105    27  L   22.29
7105    27  L   2.00
```

Conditions for plot are:

1. All the lines should be on one plot
2. Plot (for line) is grouped by TS, ASL and WC

and I am trying something like this:

```
  ggplot(df2, aes(LPD, ASL, TS, colour=WC)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point()
```

Its all the mess... may be you could help me with better view in plot.

Because the above might be a lot confusing for many, I will make it a little simpler:

```
grp LPD
1   0.56744
1   0.4200938
2   0.070033616
2   0.065484951
3   0.327293
3   0.4718639
3   0.539516903
3   0.672646939
3   0.769603286
3   0.560730825
3   0.592725708
4   0.27415791
4   0.17706706
4   0.084262982
4   0.220420565
5   1.066580889
5   0.663611983
5   0.005299676
5   0.180121466
5   0.055205502
6   0.435355273
6   0.544843791
7   2.437439375
7   0.631948813
7   0.165961834
7   0.092725372
7   0.262442283
9   0.268541902
9   0.041798885
11  0.348282689
11  0.033044253
11  0.046070074
11  0.127173837
11  0.030580852
12  7.213290722
12  2.738036844
12  1.581291713
12  1.234204974
12  0.043930992
12  0.089781343
12  0.077482862
12  0.056506104
12  0.007676594
```

Comment: What do you want the x and y axis of the final plot to be?

Comment: Y = LPD and X is free from anything.. so for each WC, ASL and TS, there will be a step plot (almost).

Comment: A step plot would still require a continuous x axis...

Comment: Are you looking for this: `ggplot(df, aes(x= 1:nrow(df),y = LPD, colour=WC)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_grid(ASL ~ TS)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP isn't fully clear what the desired output is. However, concluding from the comments it might be something like this:

[image]

To create this plot, the data need to be reshaped from wide to long format. The long format is preferred by `ggplot2`. For this, `melt()` from the `data.table` package is used.

#### Read data

```
library(data.table)
df2 <- fread(
  "WC     ASL  TS  LPD
  7101    3   L   573.57
  7101    3   L   323.33
  7102    4   R   113.36
  7102    4   R   3.05
  7103    7   L   204.72
  7103    7   L   123.65
  7104    21  R   252.36
  7104    21  R   225.74
  7104    21  R   147.79
  7104    21  R   151.47
  7105    27  L   350.51
  7105    27  L   41.61
  7105    27  L   22.29
  7105    27  L   2.00"
)
```

#### Prepare data

```
# reshape from wide to long format 
molten <- melt(setDT(df2), id = "LPD")
# ensure that factor levels are in order of appearance
molten[, value := forcats::fct_inorder(value)]

str(molten)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 42 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ LPD     : num  573.57 323.33 113.36 3.05 204.72 ...
# $ variable: Factor w/ 3 levels "WC","ASL","TS": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ value   : Factor w/ 12 levels "7101","7102",..: 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 4 ...
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Note that `melt()` has collected (or gathered) all values of the `WC`, `ASL`, and `TS` columns in one `value` column which is of class `character` afterwards.

When plotting, `ggplot2` implicitely turns characters to factors thereby using the alphabetical sort order for the levels. This means that the values of `ASL` be plotted in the order 21, 27, 3, 4, 7 instead of 3, 4, 7, 21, 27.

To keep the order of values as the appear in the data, the coercion to factor is done explicitely by using the handy `fct_inorder()` function from the `forcats` package.

#### Plot data

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(molten, aes(x = value, y = LPD)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw()
```

### Edit 1

The OP has given additional data. These can be plotted using `geom_step()` with

```
ggplot(DT2, aes(x = grp, y = LPD)) + geom_point() + geom_step() + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Note that the x-axis shows `grp` as continuous scale.

### Edit 2

According to the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754928/multiple-lines-plot-using-multiple-groups-in-data/43757218#comment74559405_43757218), the OP expects *to get lines as "step-lines"*. Unfortunately, the OP hasn't specfied what exactly to be displayed along the x-axis. So these are another wild guesses of what the OP might expect to see:

```
DT2[, grp := factor(grp)]
ggplot(DT2, aes(x = seq_len(nrow(DT2)), y = LPD, group = grp, colour = grp)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_step() + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Note that here the data points are numbered consecutively. These numbers are shown on the x-axis. Data points are connected by a step function group-wise. In addition, the groups are colour-coded.

A more compact display will result if the data points are numbered *within* each group so that each group starts with 1.

```
DT2[, rn := factor(rowid(grp))]
ggplot(DT2, aes(x = rn, y = LPD, group = grp, colour = grp)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_step() + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: I added some more details to the original question to make it easy to understand. Thanks for your help.

Comment: thanks again, but i was thinking to get lines as "step-lines", if we do not take factors on x axis, is it possible?

Comment: @MadhuSareen Hmm, this doesn't make things clearer. It's a lot of speculation to imagine what you're after. Please, define clearly what to display on the x-axis or [edit] your Q and add a draft (hand-sketched or whatever) of the expected result. Thank you.